# Span variable not being read in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website that receives parameters in the URL address (`www.xxx.html?name=David`)

then I assign the value to the html text like this:

```
<span name="uname" id="uname"> </span>, I'd like to thank you 

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     var userName = getParameterByName('uname');
     document.getElementById("uname").textContent = userName;
});
</script>
```

up to this point everything works well

now when I try to read again the value in `uname` in the PHP file in order to send it in the email I have two issues

1. the parameter is not received - `emailText = $_POST['uname'];`
2. when trying to debug I see the `HTML` file and `js` file being loaded and can be debugged but the `PHP` file doesn't exist in the file tree of the debug

*BUT* it is being loaded and read because other variables are being read and sent correctly to the email.

Comment: try `emailText = $_GET['name'];`

Comment: Theoretically, your code should read as `$emailText = $_POST['uname'];` since that alone `emailText =...`, PHP would be throwing you an undefined constant notice. In either case, PHP would be throwing you something else; an undefined index.

Comment: @ShaharGalukman did you mean $_GET['**uname**']; ?

Comment: As a side note, the reason you did not see the php file in the file tree is because php is a server-side language. It renders your html, js, etc..

Comment: @KukulaMula corresponding to the example URI you try to retrieve the parameter from I'd keep my original comment intact.
www.xxx.html?name=David => name=David => $_GET['name']

Answer (score 3):

When [submitting a form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-processing) the user agent (browser) will build a form data set from
"[Succesful controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)".

A [Control](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls) is one of the following:

- buttons
- checkboxes
- radio buttons
- menus
- text input
- file select
- hidden controls
- object controls

Only these fields will be submitted when you submit a form. A `<span>` is not part of that.

If you want to add a value with JavaScript to the form that is not inside of a text input, I suggest that you use a hidden input to do so.

```
<input name="uname" type="hidden" value="value">
```

When you edit the span, you should then also change this hidden field to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use span with name attribute.

Read this 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

If you want to post, use form + proper input element.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

And still, it's not very clear you are really trying to do, show us the whole page ...

Answer (score 0):

If I need to get value of span ill do something like this

```
<span data-name="someTextHere">...</span> # data-name will not visible in browser unless page source mode
```

and you can access it by using `($(this).data('name'))`

Ex

```
var userName = ($(this).data('name'));
```

And this article [Submit Form Using Ajax, PHP and jQuery](https://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/) will helps 
you to  pass data without `Undefined Index Error`.